# What is the polynomial corresponding to WeightToFee in the official library?

Tags: weight, weighttofee

About Code:
https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-parachain-template/blob/main/runtime/src/lib.rs#L130-L145

```rust
pub struct WeightToFee;
impl WeightToFeePolynomial for WeightToFee {
    type Balance = Balance;
    fn polynomial() -> WeightToFeeCoefficients<Self::Balance> {
        // in Rococo, extrinsic base weight (smallest non-zero weight) is mapped to 1 MILLIUNIT:
        // in our template, we map to 1/10 of that, or 1/10 MILLIUNIT
        let p = MILLIUNIT / 10;
        let q = 100 * Balance::from(ExtrinsicBaseWeight::get());
        smallvec![WeightToFeeCoefficient {
            degree: 1,
            negative: false,
            coeff_frac: Perbill::from_rational(p % q, q),
            coeff_integer: p / q,
        }]
    }
}
```

I don't really understand what `Perbill:: from_Rational (P % q, q)` means.
Has anyone tried to plot this polynomial in rectangular coordinates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It just approximates `p/q` (in this line, `(p % q) / q`) as a `PerBill`: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/2195448d01fc935912d8cf543be6d609f5899652/primitives/arithmetic/src/per_things.rs#L265L283

---

EDIT: I see the question is more about the polynomial than the `from_rational` function.

The polynomial is just of the form `a*x^n + b*x^(n-1) + ...` where `x` is the independent variable, `{a, b, ...}` are coefficients and the exponent of each term is its degree. You see that the polynomial actually returns a `vec` of `WeightToFeeCoefficient` structs. The `degree` tells you the exponent, `negative` tells you if it's positive or negative, and `coeff_integer + coeff_frac` tells you the constant coefficient on the term.

Since there is only one term in this polynomial, and `Weight` is the independent variable, it would be the function:

```
weight fee: Balance = (p / q + (p % q) / q) * Weight;
```

This isn't the *final* fee, as the length fee will also be added and then the weight fee will be adjusted based on the `NextFeeMultiplier`.

Comment: If `p` is `10000000` and `q` is `1250000000`, then the corresponding polynomial is `Perbill(80000000)*x`. So how much balance does `1 weight` correspond to?

Comment: Edited the post to address

Comment: You mention `(p % q) / q` approximates `p/q` but I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around it. Can you explain it a bit more? Why `(p % q) / q` ?